# node 6.11.3 socket.io error: 'Cannot read property \'on\' of undefined'

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have set up my server with the following:

```
const socket = require('socket.io');

// Start the app by listening on <port>

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(server);

server
  .listen(config.port)
  .on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A client is connected!');
    socket.setTimeout(30 * 1000);
  });

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

At this point 'A client is connected' is logged multiple times and the socket is initialized. However when I try to use the socket to send an event like this:

```
const io = require('../../../server').io;

      io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.emit('verified');
      });
```

The error below is produced:

```
'TypeError: Cannot read property \'on\' of undefined'
```

This was working perfectly with node v 4.2.2, however, we have now upgraded to 6.11.3 and get this error.

Any help?

Comment: https://github.com/RUJodan/Source-React/blob/master/server.js here's how I do my socket to server attachment

Comment: probably cause you're calling the `on` method on `server.listen()` and not on the `io` object you created with : `const io = socket(server);`